# JQuery conflict (maybe?) Hide/Show Div based on Radio Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

This is driving me crazy. I have tried every different ways to do this. Trying to show/hive a div based on a radio box selection. Below is my code into my main.js :

```
$("input[name='payment_method']").click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "payment_method_cod") {
        $("#checkout_insurance").show();
    } else {
        $("#checkout_insurance").hide();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="checkout_insurance">
    <h2>Checkout with Insurance</h2>
</div>

<div id="payment" class="woocommerce-checkout-payment">

    <ul class="payment_methods methods">
        <li class="payment_method_cod">
            <input id="payment_method_cod" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="cod" data-order_button_text="" checked="checked">

            <label for="payment_method_cod">
                ...
        </li>
        <li class="payment_method_firstdata">
            <input id="payment_method_firstdata" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="firstdata" data-order_button_text="">

            <label for="payment_method_firstdata">
                ....
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I cant get to work. If I place another cdn of the jQuery on the footer, the function works, however messes up a lot of other stuff. jQuery is being loaded on the header. I am current using jQuery 1.11.3.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: pls include html as well

Comment: @Marcio Please add the HTML code to the original post, not in a comment.

Comment: Sorry! Just added. Thank you guys. But I still cant get it to work. :(

Comment: Guys, please go to : https://www.apneapros.com I just changed the div#checkout_insurance to #order_comments_field because I dont have the #checkout_insurance ready on the server. Add something to the cart and proceed to checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:checked` selector to check if the radio element with id `payment_method_cod` is checked or not.

`$('#payment_method_cod:checked')` will return `true/false` based on the condition if the radio button is checked or not and `toggle` it, when `true`, the element `#checkout_insurance` will be shown.
Assuming the id's used in the code are unique.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('change', "input[name='payment_method']", function() {
  $("#checkout_insurance").toggle($('#payment_method_cod').is(':checked'));
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkout_insurance">
  <h2>Checkout with Insurance</h2>
</div>

<div id="payment" class="woocommerce-checkout-payment">

  <ul class="payment_methods methods">
    <li class="payment_method_cod">
      <input id="payment_method_cod" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="cod" data-order_button_text="" checked="checked">

      <label for="payment_method_cod">Payment</label>
      ...
    </li>
    <li class="payment_method_firstdata">
      <input id="payment_method_firstdata" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="firstdata" data-order_button_text="">

      <label for="payment_method_firstdata">FirstData</label>
      ....
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would add that to my existing code or just replace everything?

Comment: `$('#payment_method_cod:checked')` will be true, always.

Comment: What is that mean? Is your code all I need to place it or ..?

Comment: This is only hiding my div. It does not show even when the right radio button is selected.

Comment: @Marcio You want to hide it when none of the radio is selected?

Comment: I want to show when "cod" is selected and hide when "cod" is not selected.

Comment: Its not working on my site. Does it matter where I load my main.js? Right now its on the footer. I'm doing on the server, and now I am getting this console error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(anonymous function) @ main.js:1 –

Comment: @Marcio Ok, so the functionality is correct. The error is because you havent included jQuery on page or you are using the jQuery before it is being loaded

Comment: Guys, please go to : https://www.apneapros.com I just changed the div#checkout_insurance to #order_comments_field because I dont have the #checkout_insurance ready on the server. Add something to the cart and proceed to checkout.

Comment: jquery is being loaded on the header I believe. Is that correct?

Comment: @Marcio I don't see any element with id `checkout_insurance` on the page

Comment: Yeah, thats what I said before, I dont have that element on the server (only local) so I just used #order_comments_field instead. Also, I replaced $ to jQuery  on the code

Comment: @Marcio Didn't find that element also, the element should be present in the DOM to work on it

Comment: Its because its being hidden from your code. However its there. Right below "ship to a different address" #order_comments_field its actually a <p> tag.

Comment: Once I ran the code into the console, it works. Why is it not working for me? Do I need to have another line of code like "check what is the selection"? or "execute the code"?

Comment: YES!!! It worked! Thank you much! What was the difference? Why wasn't working before? Just for curiosity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92122/discussion-between-tushar-and-marcio).

Comment: @Marcio Check http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/, as the element is added dynamically, the event handler didn't work as the element was not present in DOM when the event was bound on the elements

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name='payment_method']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "payment_method_cod" && $(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('show');
    } else {
        alert('hide');
    }
});
```

Please use `.change()` on checkbox use `.click()` on button. 
Try this approach this will select change event on checkbox and check if the id of the checkbox is `payment_method_cod` it will then show or hide depending on checked property

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/4skpw18v/)

Comment: Still not working. :( Did you guys read the part that if I load jQuery on the footer it does work? But I know I cant load more that once right? It messes up with other stuff too. Please help!

Comment: if you put it on header what error do you get in console?

Comment: Did you try alert or debugger.. please install firebug in Firefox then put a debugger like this : debugger; this will give you a break point facility to investigate the error

Comment: Guys, please go to : apneapros.com I just changed the div#checkout_insurance to #order_comments_field because I dont have the #checkout_insurance ready on the server. Add something to the cart and proceed to checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your code a bit :

```
$("input[name='payment_method']").click(function () {
var _this = $(this);
if (_this.val() == "cod") {
    $("#checkout_insurance").show();
} else {
    $("#checkout_insurance").hide();
}
```

});

Comment: Sir you forgot one important part of the code `if ($(this).attr("id") == "payment_method_cod") {`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me if you have two radio button and you ant to show hide sections accordingly then user val() instead of attr('id')

Comment: So, how it would be the correct version of the full code?

Comment: Still not working. :( Maybe because there is a default choice already?

Comment: Can you please tell me the error message of console and alert(_this.val()) and tell me what is being printed in alert

Comment: There are no errors on the console I guess. This is what is being printed: `alert(_this.val())
VM1439:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: _this is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM1439:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM1434:904InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM1434:837InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM1434:693`

Comment: the best way for this to replicate your own code make a fiddle. there is an `undefined in your code`

Comment: what you mean? How should I do this? this is a checkout page of woocommerce

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvdJpb                                              I have created a codepen for you, check this.

Comment: Does it matter where I load my main.js? Right now its on the footer. I'm doing on the server, and now I am getting this console error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(anonymous function) @ main.js:1

Comment: Guys, please go to : apneapros.com I just changed the div#checkout_insurance to #order_comments_field because I dont have the #checkout_insurance ready on the server. Add something to the cart and proceed to checkout.